# DHCP Warning Sign Icon On Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, domain-controller, dhcp-server, warning

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Domain Controller. I have the roles AD, DHCP, and DNS installed on this server. I noticed today that there was a warning sign on my IPv4 setting, but not on my IPv6 settings. Can someone please tell me what this means, and also what would be the correct way to fix it

[image: DHCP]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is the Technet DHCP Console Icon Reference Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg722802%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

That icon means:

> DHCP server warning. Available addresses for server scopes are 90 percent or more leased and in use. This means that the server is nearly depleted of available addresses to lease to clients.

Comment: What would be the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Expand your scope or reduce the lease duration so that unused ip addresses that have been allocated can be used by new clients.

Comment: @nate Depends.  You basically have two options - make more addresses available, (by expanding the scope), or reducing the number of used addresses (by moving existing clients to another subnet).